# Compiling JD2XX for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, compilation, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries

For Openhab2 there is a binding add-on called [RFXCOM](https://github.com/openhab/openhab2-addons/tree/master/addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.rfxcom). The problem however is that this add-on uses JD2XX which is not compatible with the ARM architecture of the Raspberry Pi.

I have found a Github repository with the source that you can use to compile a *.so file: https://github.com/0x6a77/JD2XX

A little change to the Makefile to use the correct Java path (zulu-8-armhf-embedded instead of (oracle-7).

Running `sudo make jni` creates a `*.so` file which I copied to `/usr/lib` (inside the java library path). However I still get the error that the Raspberry Pi can't open the shared library due to it being 32-bit. How can you compile a shared library that works for ARM with the source provided by the Github repository.

Error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/var/lib/openhab2/tmp/libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so: 
/var/lib/openhab2/tmp/libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
```

The Raspberry Pi has a fresh installation of [Openhabian](https://github.com/openhab/openhabian/releases).

Link to the issue on Github: https://github.com/openhab/openhab2-addons/issues/2316#issuecomment-304795652

EDIT:

```
11:00:52.291 [ERROR] [rnal.discovery.RFXComBridgeDiscovery] - Error occurred during discovery
java.io.IOException: device not found (2)
    at jd2xx.JD2XX.listDevices(Native Method)
    at jd2xx.JD2XX.listDevicesByDescription(JD2XX.java:785)
    at org.openhab.binding.rfxcom.internal.discovery.RFXComBridgeDiscovery.discoverRfxcom(RFXComBridgeDiscovery.java:89)
    at org.openhab.binding.rfxcom.internal.discovery.RFXComBridgeDiscovery.startScan(RFXComBridgeDiscovery.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.smarthome.config.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryService.startScan(AbstractDiscoveryService.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.smarthome.config.discovery.internal.DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.startScan(DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.smarthome.config.discovery.internal.DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.startScans(DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.smarthome.config.discovery.internal.DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.startScan(DiscoveryServiceRegistryImpl.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.smarthome.io.rest.core.discovery.DiscoveryResource.scan(DiscoveryResource.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)[157:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)[158:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)[155:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)[155:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)[155:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)[155:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)[155:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2]
    at com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher.internal.ServletContainerBridge.service(ServletContainerBridge.java:76)[10:com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.publisher:5.3.1.201602281253]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)[81:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)[81:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)[172:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)[79:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)[172:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[81:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)[172:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[80:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)[72:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[83:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[83:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
11:01:02.868 [WARN ] [e.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession] - Unknown pty opcode value: 42
```

Comment: Is your file name libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so ? I can see the file name of the shared library libjd2xx.so in the Makefile. Tell me what happened if you do with TestListener.sh in the test directory? I think It's a LD_LIBRARY_PATH or java.library.path problem.

Comment: The shared library is called libjd2xx.so only after openhab2 is copying it gets some number suffixes. I copied it to /usr/lib/ which is the path and chmod 755 to be able to read it. What do you mean TestListener?

Comment: Well, don't mind TestListener.sh under https://github.com/0x6a77/JD2XX/tree/master/jd2xx/test. Can you try this script for you? java -Xcheck:jni -Djava.library.path="where to your lib path" -cp "where to/jd2xx.jar:." TestListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JD2XX.java file, you can see the mechanism how to load a dll, so or some other type of library depending on OS.

```
static {
    String dataModel = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();;

    StringBuilder lib = new StringBuilder("/jni/");

    if (osName.contains("win"))
        lib.append("win/");
    else if (osName.contains("linux"))
        lib.append("linux/");
    else if (osName.contains("mac"))
        lib.append("mac/");
    else
        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Loading JD2XX JNI: Unsupported operating system ("+osName+")");

    if (dataModel.equals("32"))
        lib.append("x86_32/");
    else if (dataModel.equals("64"))
        lib.append("x86_64/");
    else
        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError("Loading JD2XX JNI: Unknown runtime data model ("+dataModel+")");

    if (osName.contains("win"))
        lib.append("jd2xx.dll");
    else if (osName.contains("linux"))
        lib.append("libjd2xx.so");
    else if (osName.contains("mac"))
        lib.append("libjd2xx.jnilib");

    try {
        NativeUtils.loadLibraryFromJar(lib.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The loadLibraryFromJar method from NativeUtils creates temp directory and copy the right library for OS to temp directory then call the System.load method eventually.
So, I think you should modify this part of source code like the code as follows, if possible.

```
static
{
   System.load("/var/lib/openhab2/tmp/libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so");
}
```

or

```
static
{
   System.load("/usr/lib/libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so");
}
```

There are several ways to make this job work re-setting the 'java.library.path' order to indicate the /usr/lib directory first then use the code below.

Or you can rename the library name, libjd2xx5892592723514582617.so to libjd2xx.so in the /usr/lib which is usually in the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' variable.

then, our code in the JD2XX.java can be used instead,

```
static
{
   System.loadLibrary("jd2xx");
}
```

I think it works..

Comment: You were right about where the error came from. I recompiled both the *.so and the *.jar and that solved it so i'll grant the bounty to you. However I get a new error. Nonetheless you solved the problem so i'll grant the bounty to you. The new error is in the original post If you still have a second to spare :-)

Comment: Well, thank you in advance. I found this article fot you at https://github.com/openhab/openhab2-addons/issues/1312. First you have to follow the pdf file http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux.pdf then, If the instruction doesn't work, then try to get the usb mount point 755 permission. sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0. Could you tell me what happened after all this done?

Comment: Nope neither seem to be working, exactly the same stack trace. unloaded both drivers and chmodded the ttyUSB0 device.

Comment: I found the article of this issue..https://github.com/openhab/openhab2-addons/issues/625. Have you read a comments of RobertOnGit?

Comment: Yes but that is not using the discovery component so it negates the point of using JD2XX right?

Comment: have a problem with your peocess i think you have to check the serial port working first using a emulator